# wrong result while counting activity life cycle states

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

i have created two activities. i have done the same code for my first activity. but that's working fine. but while i am switching to the second activity the counter values are not increasing but the logcat is showing all the states right. and there is a problem in logcat showing "error opening trace file".

the onCreate calls, onResume calls and onCreate always shows value 1 and onRestart always shows 0. wheres it works correctly for activity_one

```
package course.labs.activitylab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {

    private static final String RESTART_KEY = "restart";
    private static final String RESUME_KEY = "resume";
    private static final String START_KEY = "start";
    private static final String CREATE_KEY = "create";

    // String for LogCat documentation
    private final static String TAG = "Lab-ActivityTwo";

    // Lifecycle counters

    // TODO:
    // Create counter variables for onCreate(), onRestart(), onStart() and
    // onResume(), called mCreate, etc.
    // You will need to increment these variables' values when their
    // corresponding lifecycle methods get called

    private int mCreate ;
    private int mRestart ;
    private int mStart ;
    private int mResume ;



    // TODO: Create variables for each of the TextViews, called
        // mTvCreate, etc. 

    private TextView mTvCreate ;
    private TextView mTvRestart;
    private TextView mTvStart;
    private TextView mTvResume;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

        // TODO: Assign the appropriate TextViews to the TextView variables
        // Hint: Access the TextView by calling Activity's findViewById()
        // textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        mTvCreate = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.create);
        mTvRestart = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.restart);
        mTvStart = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.start);
        mTvResume = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.resume);



        Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClose); 
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO:
                // This function closes Activity Two
                // Hint: use Context's finish() method
                finish();


            }
        });

        // Check for previously saved state
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            // TODO:
            // Restore value of counters from saved state
            // Only need 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            mCreate = savedInstanceState.getInt(CREATE_KEY);
            mRestart = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESTART_KEY);
            mStart = savedInstanceState.getInt(START_KEY);
            mResume = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESUME_KEY);


        }

        // TODO: Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "I am in onCreate method");


        // TODO:
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface via the displayCounts() method

        mCreate += 1;
        displayCounts();



    }

    // Lifecycle callback methods overrides

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // TODO: Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "I am in onStart method");

        // TODO:
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface

        mStart += 1;
        displayCounts();


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // TODO: Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "I am in onStart method");

        // TODO:
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface

        mResume += 1;
        displayCounts();


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // TODO: Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "I am in onPause method");


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // TODO: Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "I am in onStop method");


    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

        // TODO: Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "I am in onRestart method");

        // TODO:
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface


        mRestart += 1;
        displayCounts();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // TODO: Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "I am in onDestroy method");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO:
        // Save counter state information with a collection of key-value pairs
        // 4 lines of code, one for every count variable

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(CREATE_KEY, mCreate);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(START_KEY, mStart);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESUME_KEY, mResume);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESTART_KEY, mRestart);

        //savedInstanceState.getInt(CREATE_KEY);
        //savedInstanceState.getInt(RESUME_KEY);
        //savedInstanceState.getInt(RESTART_KEY);
        //savedInstanceState.getInt(START_KEY);




    }

    // Updates the displayed counters
    public void displayCounts() {

        mTvCreate.setText("onCreate() calls: " + mCreate);
        mTvStart.setText("onStart() calls: " + mStart);
        mTvResume.setText("onResume() calls: " + mResume);
        mTvRestart.setText("onRestart() calls: " + mRestart);

    }
}
```

the logcat shows correct result:

```
03-06 23:26:38.179: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onPause method
03-06 23:26:38.189: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onRestart method
03-06 23:26:38.189: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onStart method
03-06 23:26:38.199: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onResume method
03-06 23:26:38.430: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onStop method
03-06 23:26:38.430: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onDestroy method
03-06 23:26:38.770: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onPause method
03-06 23:26:38.900: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onStop method
03-06 23:26:38.900: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onDestroy method
03-06 23:26:46.688: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): Oncreate1
03-06 23:26:46.688: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onStart method
03-06 23:26:46.688: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onResume method
03-06 23:26:52.233: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onPause method
03-06 23:26:52.283: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onCreate method
03-06 23:26:52.283: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onStart method
03-06 23:26:52.283: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onStart method
03-06 23:26:52.593: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onStop method
03-06 23:27:04.115: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onPause method
03-06 23:27:04.155: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onRestart method
03-06 23:27:04.155: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onStart method
03-06 23:27:04.155: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onResume method
03-06 23:27:04.385: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onStop method
03-06 23:27:04.395: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onDestroy method
03-06 23:27:06.277: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onPause method
03-06 23:27:06.337: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onCreate method
03-06 23:27:06.337: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onStart method
03-06 23:27:06.337: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onStart method
03-06 23:27:06.617: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onStop method
03-06 23:27:14.825: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onPause method
03-06 23:27:14.855: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onRestart method
03-06 23:27:14.855: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onStart method
03-06 23:27:14.855: I/Lab-ActivityOne(30424): I am in onResume method
03-06 23:27:15.095: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onStop method
03-06 23:27:15.095: I/Lab-ActivityTwo(30424): I am in onDestroy method
```

Comment: Can you tell us the output that you're expecting, and the output you're actually getting?

Comment: it is always showing the value of onCreate class, onStart calls and onResume calls 1 and onRestart call 0. but the value should increment when i switch back to activity_one and come back to activity_second.

Comment: I don't see any code to open your second activity. How are you opening second activity?

Comment: i have call that from my first activity as
public void onClick(View v) { startActivity() method
    
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class));

   }

Comment: I think you're confused. Every time you open Activity2 the counters will be restarted (in Activity2 of course). Every time you use `startActivity` a new instance will be created.

Answer (score 0):

By calling finish() in onClick() to end ActivityTwo, your onSaveInstanceState() will never be called. You can add log statement in that method to verify.

Comment: what should i use instead?

Comment: Since the rules for when the state is saved and restored depend on situations that you can't easily predict, I'd recommend using a different approach. Using shared preferences is probably the easiest. Here's a page that shows how to do that: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html